# Body.transformToString function in AWS SDK does not print file contents

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

The transformToString() in below route does not work:

```
  const fileKey = req.body.filePath;
  const input = {
    Bucket: AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileKey,
  };
  const command = new GetObjectCommand(input);
  const response = await s3Client.send(command);
  const { Body } = response;

  console.log(Body); // This prints the Boyd Object, Body is NOT empty
  const bodyContents = await Body.transformToString();
  console.log(bodyContents); // This does not print anything. This is empty
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `transformToString('utf8')`? Or if you would like to return base64 data:
`transformToString('base64')`